# How to define association in a decorator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, decorator

I do not want to pollute my model with complex associations (to have only necessary validations and simple associations in AR models)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visible_comments,
    -> {
      where(deleted_at: nil).joins(:user).where(users: { active: true }) 
    }, class_name: 'Comment'
end
```

I would want to move this association into a decorator class for posts

```
PostsDecorator.new(posts).preload(:visible_comments)
```

Is there a way to create a decorator class so it will be possible to declare associations on it (to preload associations for example)?

Comment: Is there a way to do *what*, exactly?

Comment: @jvillian add decorator so it will be possible to define associations in it

Comment: The only way I can think of is making your decorator a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` - associations are defined per class in AR. I would say this is an overapplication of a design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're wanting to do. "Declare associations on it" (the decorator) could well be a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Why not do something like:

```
class PostsDecorator < SimpleDelegator

  def visible_comments
    Comment.where(post: component, deleted_at: nil)
  end

private

  def component
    @component ||= self.__getobj__
  end

end
```

(Or something along those lines.)

Then you'll be able to do:

```
PostsDecorator.new(posts).visible_comments
```

As to this idea of "preloading", well, I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: I updated the question and tried to state the problem more clear. Is it more clear now what I want?

Comment: Seems a bit like shaving the yak to me.